# Parsing the string in bash and setting it in variables

Tags: string, bash, shell, for-loop

please help in this issue :

I have the string (In future the lenght string and elements in string chagne all time) for example :

```
ataat1, atata2|ololo1 ololo2|pishpish1 pishpish1
```

How with using cycle I can to get this values and using as variable : (ex)

first step of loop I have two variables s1 = ataat1 and s2 = ataat2, in the next step s1=ololo1 and s2=ololo2

Please help!!! and again the elements in string all time change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
s='ataat1, atata2|ololo1 ololo2|pishpish1 pishpish1'

while IFS='[, ]' read -r s1 s2; do
   echo "s1=[$s1] s2=[$s2]"
done < <(printf "%b\n" "${s//|/\\n}")
s1=[ataat1] s2=[atata2]
s1=[ololo1] s2=[ololo2]
s1=[pishpish1] s2=[pishpish1]
```

Comment: No it is not a noob question.

Comment: Perhaps `-d '|'` instead of the sed/sub-shell? Though that requires ensuring that there is a trailing `|` in the input string.